# GIMP path not using expected colors

Tags: gimp, path, stroke

I am making a dashed line in Gimp by making a new layer, drawing a path, clicking "Stroke Path" in the tool options, and then selecting the dashed line style in the Stroke Path window.

[image]

My foreground color is black. I would expect this line to also be black. Instead it's filling with a brown gradient, similar to a gradient that I used for the bottom rectangle in this image.

[image]

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities I can think of that might be to blame, although there may be more.

1. Check the colour mode by clicking *Image > Mode*. Sounds like you might be in Indexed colour mode. It should be in RGB colour.
2. You have Stroke Line set to "Pattern". Change it to "Solid color" instead.

Comment: #2 was the solution. Changing it to "solid color" solved it. Thank you!